# Return-Oriented Programming: Why literal number used in ROP chain?

Tags: assembly, exploit, windows-security

Following [an article](http://www.fuzzysecurity.com/tutorials/expDev/7.html) introducing ROP on Windows, I found that the author put some literal numbers in the ROP chain.

The code snippet generating the shellcode:

```
rop += struct.pack('<L',0x10013b1c) # POP EBX # RETN
rop += struct.pack('<L',0xffffffff) # will be 0x1
rop += struct.pack('<L',0x100319d3) # INC EBX # FPATAN # RETN
rop += struct.pack('<L',0x100319d3) # INC EBX # FPATAN # RETN
                                    #------------------------------------[dwSize (0x1) -> EBX]-#
rop += struct.pack('<L',0x10030361) # POP EAX # RETN
rop += struct.pack('<L',0x90909090) # NOP
                                    #---------------------------------------------[NOP -> EAX]-#
```

From my understanding, the ROP chain should consist of memory addresses that pointing to the gadget, so CPU will execute the instructions at the corresponding memory address sequentially. Yet, the author put `0xffffffff` and `0x90909090` in the gadget chain.

Can somebody explain the use of these literal numbers in the ROP chain? Thank you.

Comment: `pop EBX` instruction uses next dword in stack as data, not as next gadget's address

Answer (score 2):

- In this ROP chain, the author needs `ebx` to be `0x1`. However, an entry on the stack in this binary is 4 bytes as this is a 32-bit binary. To fulfill this entry, the number is supposed to be `0x00000001`, but writing of null bytes is known to be bad in exploitation since functions like `strcpy` will stop processing the input when it hits null bytes. Therefore, the author pop the value of `0xffffffff` for ebx (using the first 2 lines) and then increase the value on `ebx` by `1`. This wraps around the maximum value on 32-bit system and the value becomes `0x00000001`.
- For the second literal number `0x90909090`, this is a [NOP-sled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_slide). `0x90` is the `NO-oPeration` and it does nothing. This maybe a nop-sled to fulfill the buffer that the author is trying to overflow.
- You can also see other literal numbers in bypassing ASLR that includes overwriting the Global Offset Table of a dynamically linked binary. In this exploitation technique, particular functions in libc will be at a particular offset from the libc base address. You will need to find this libc base address and from the offset obtained from the libc, you can calculate the address of those functions and use them in your exploit. Read more [here](https://sploitfun.wordpress.com/2015/05/08/bypassing-aslr-part-iii/).